# How to find $\bigg(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\bigg)_q$, given $\bigg(\frac{\partial \big(\ln (P) \big)}{\partial T}\bigg)_q$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

How can I find, partial derivative of $P$ with respect to $T$ at a given $q$
$$\bigg(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\bigg)_q$$ 
given that I know, partial derivative of $\ln P$ with respect to $T$ at a given $q$
$$\bigg(\frac{\partial \big(\ln (P) \big)}{\partial T}\bigg)_q$$

Thanks so much.

Comment: Does $(f)_q$ represent the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to $q$?

Comment: no it represents partial derivative of f at constant q. $(\partial f/ \partial t)_q$ represents partial derivative of f with respect to t at constant q.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a smooth function $f$ you have:
$$
\frac{d\log{f(x)}}{dx}=\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} \Rightarrow f'(x)=f(x) \frac{d\log{f(x)}}{dx}
$$
With you notation this gives:
$$
\left(\frac{\partial P}{\partial T}\right)_q=P(T,q)\left(\frac{\partial \log{P}}{\partial T}\right)_q
$$

Answer (score 0):

Notice that:

$$\frac{\partial \big(\ln (P) \big)}{\partial T} = \frac{1}{P}\frac{\partial P }{\partial T},$$

or equivalently:
$$\frac{\partial P }{\partial T} = P \frac{\partial \big(\ln (P) \big)}{\partial T}.$$

Moreover, notice that you don't need to care about $q$ since it is assumed constant in both the expressions.